# Outputting Jenkins Stacktrace information all the time

Tags: ruby, jenkins, selenium-webdriver

We're running a Ruby CI server on Jenkins, and occassionally when we get a serious error we get a Stacktrace. Contained in this information is a few important bits, but mainly our `NodeIP` and `OS`.

I was just wondering if there is a Jenkins / Ruby Command to output this. I've tried an ip based command but that doesn't work with virtual servers.

Example output

```
System info: host: 'node-stuff', ip: '12.34.56.78', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_102'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.25.426923 (idkey), userDataDir=C:\Users\ieuser\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir2312_10082}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=54.0.2840.99, platform=WIN8_1, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
```

Comment: Is the information you want available as part of  `http://your_jenkins_ip/log/all`? If so, you can create a custom logger to show the relevant information only.

Comment: Possibly, but that area is a Full Administrator access area. I'm not 100%. I can find out later.

Comment: EDIT: That just shows that each run ran, and then finished. Not really what I'm looking for.

I've added what I'm looking for in the Main